# Dropping icon onto excel Cell rather than the actual content

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Word you can drag and drop files onto the document and have it show as an link to the file rather than copying the contents of the file onto the the word document itself. When double clicked this would open the file.

Q: Is this possible to do in Excel?

I want to be able to have the icons available to launch the images/text with, instead of actually have the images and text appear in the excel.

Comment: At home and without excel (home desktop has open office), but I have the strong impression that you can do that with insert link, hyperlink, subfile `file://`

Comment: Would this work for other users' though?  If I were to send across this file with a hyperlink, they wouldn't be able to open it since it would be referencing my machines locations, right?

Comment: Correct. It would not embed the file. Merely its location. That might work for you or not (in my case I link to files on a sharepoint which is accessable to all relevant people and this opens the latest copy of that file on the sharepoint. If you want to embed a static version and have it work even for external people... not idea).

Comment: If it works for you in Word, it should work in Excel.  That is, if in your current situation you can set up links like this in Word, send the Word doc to someone, and then they can open it just fine, it should work in Excel, too.

Answer (score 2):

Drag & Drop doesn't seem to work the same as Word, so in Excel you do this by embedding it as an object from the menu.

*Note: these steps may vary depending on the version of Excel you are using.*

1. Go to the `Insert` menu
2. Select the icon to insert an `Object`
3. In the following dialog choose `Create from file`
4. Use <kbd>Browse...</kbd> to select the file you want
5. Check both `Link to file` and `Display as icon` boxes
6. Change the icon if you want
7. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]